# Loop through code while listening for socket.io message

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a page that connects to the node.js server and uses socket.io.

- Q1 - I want to **always loop** through some code
- Q2 - I want the page to **listen for socket.io messages**
- Q3 - I want them to do ***both*** at the same time.

Here's my basic outline...

```
loop {
  doSomeCodeHere;
}

//socket.io code here (i know this part)
```

So basically I need both to function at the same time, any suggestions?

Comment: You know node.js is event driven, right?

Comment: yea, so does this mean that I can follow a regular js loop and on event, do something at the same time? my loop is... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457710/html5-audio-javascript-looping-but)

Comment: you can. But what i mean is that probably you don't want to use a loop on node since node works like a loop waiting for events to respond to.  Can't you do whatever you want to do in a setInterval or proper events? The simpler way would be to just setInterval call your function that you want to execute.

Comment: Well, Im a beginner in nodejs, so I dont really know much. Could you show me an example where I could **always** loop through some code and also listen to events from socket.io simultaneously?