# HTML5 audio Javascript looping but

Tags: javascript, html, loops, audio

```
function nextSong() {
    var v30 = 1;
    var v07 = 1;
    var v......[continues]
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    if (v07 == '1') {
        audioPlayer.src='wavs/1507.mp3';
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
    if (v30 == '1') {
        audioPlayer.src='wavs/1530.mp3';
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();            
    }
    if (......[continues]
}
```

This current configuration plays and loops the '1530.mp3', shouldn't it also play and loop '1507.mp3' too? Im open to any new method of doing this, like an array, which i think would be a better option. Just not so sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
audioPlayer.src='wavs/1507.mp3';
audioPlayer.src='wavs/1530.mp3';
```

You are setting the source twice on the same element, which results in it only playing the second source (1530.mp3) as it overwrites the first source (1507.mp3).

You need two audio elements to play two files.

Comment: I see. So can I make it so that the src of the audio player changes on finish. So src=1, then on done, src=2?

Comment: You can call a function at the end of playback by attaching it to the `onended` attribute on the audio element. You could use this to play a series of audio files one after the other using the same audio element.